# Linq-to-Sql Autogenerated Code Errors: "The type name {1} does not exist in the type {2}"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I am having a peculiar error when I try to add a `LinqDataClasses` object in Visual Studio.

I've got a SQL Server 2008 database that I've pulled into VS2010's Server Explorer.
When I create the `LinqDataClasses`, everything is okay, but whenever I add certain tables, I get hundreds of errors.

Most of the errors are of the type:

> *The type name {1} does not exist in the type {2}*

E.g.:

> *The type name 'Data' does not exist in the type 'MyApplication'*

These errors occur in the `LinqDataClasses` designer page (the `designer.cs` page to the `.dbml` file).

I can eliminate some of these errors by prefixing `global::` in front of every system library (e.g. `global::System.Data.Linq`), but I have used `LinqDataClasses` before and not had this issue.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the syntactic cause of these errors? Is something missing?

Comment: How do you ADD the new table? On the designer view? Did you instead try to delete and recreate the data context after you add a new table to the database?

Comment: @usr Not sure if I understand your question..But I believe all of the DLLs are present because I can use the LinqDataClasses on some tables, but not others.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, I used the designer to drag-and-drop. I have deleted and restarted several times. Even made new VS projects.

Comment: "The type name 'Data' does not exist" ... why the error? Does "Data" exist or not? (I ask you to debug the compiler error just like you would debug an error in your own code).

Comment: @usr Ok, then the answer to your question is: Yes, Data is present. Evidence: (1) `Data` (aka System.Data) seems to be found when I only use 1 table in my LinqDataClasses. (2) `Data` can be found if I prefix `global::` to `System.Data`. Note: As mentioned, prefixing `global::` is not an option because the code is autogenerated.

Comment: Is any of your classes called "System" or "Data" or something else that might alias with a system type? Maybe the problem is not having *two* classes but the specific class that you add 2nd?!

Comment: @usr I see...you are right, sorry. I had a table named System. Didn't even think about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is any of your classes called "System" or "Data" or something else that might alias with a system type? Maybe the problem is not having two classes but the specific class that you add 2nd?!

The key to solving this bug is to treat the compiler errors in the generated code the same as your own compiler errors. That leads to the deeper cause (in your case a duplicate name).